# Cannot run Ubuntu after installation. Black Screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, live-usb, dual-graphics

I installed Ubuntu LTS 20.04 beside Windows.
When I'm running Live version by USB, it's working. But when I'm trying to run from grub, i see only black screen and my keyboard is not working also. So i cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command, `nomodeset` also is not helping. And I cannot run Windows 10 as I have the same problem with black screen and keyboard.

I have a laptop with AMD A8-4500M CPU and GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7640G + HD 8570M Dual Graphics.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem before. I reinstall ubuntu again. Before installation, you need to learn the installation process from the different tutorials.